# Android App development : Help required for connecting app to internet/ taking and storing data from net

Tags: android, cloud, synchronization

I am a beginner at android app development. 
Want to know how to take data from the net and display on the app. For example : How to make an app which displays News ? Where is the news stored ? How is it updated/ How are new news added ? How is the app synced ?

If you could give me source from where to learn such things, it would be really great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better practice is use AsyncTasks to download files on background thread and update UI with onPostExecute methods called by android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Here is a good example of how you can do this:
[Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have know idea about java socket programming. You should start from sockets. Try to write small client-server application. Or simply watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgOrhLu5XUo).